# String to Float with Precision in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a better way to convert a String to a Float?

I'm using this method here:

```
std::string test = "4.9102919";

float test2 = std::atoi(test.c_str());

std::cout << test2;
```

It prints out: `4` instead of `4.9102919`.

Comment: Abd you are surprised that the output you get looks more like a integer than a float. What did you expect dobe by ?`atoi`?

Comment: You need to use `atof` in place of `atoi`.

Comment: Also consider using [`std::stof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) or [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) which are a little bit smarter than `atof` when it comes to letting you know an error was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just using the wrong function.

The behavior of `atoi` is described by its name itself: **a**scii **to** **i**nteger. That's why your input is truncated to its integer part, before being assigned to the `float` variable.

What you need is [`std::atof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof), instead: **a**scii **to** **f**loat.

Answer (score 0):

"atoi()" is for integers

You're looking for "atof()" which is for floating point

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
float test2 = std::atoi(test.c_str());
```

First converts `const char*`  to `int`, and then implicitly cast `int` to `float`.

use `std::atof`:

```
float test2 = std::atof(test.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `<std::atof>` instead of `<std::atoi>` in `float test2 = std::atoi(test.c_str());`

```
    // stof example
    #include <iostream>   // std::cout 
    #include <string>     // std::string, std::stof
    
    int main ()
    {
      std::string orbits ("686.97 365.24");
      std::string::size_type sz;     // alias of size_t
    
      float mars = std::stof (orbits,&sz);
      float earth = std::stof (orbits.substr(sz));
      std::cout << "One martian year takes " << (mars/earth) << " Earth years.\n";
      return 0;
    }
```

Possible output:
One martian year takes 1.88087 Earth years.

Comment: that is just because in the code I am taking **string** type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use C++ strings then you want the std::stod function.  atof uses C strings (char arrays) and I'm sure somewhere I was taught to avoid them in C++ when posible.

```
std::string test = "4.9102919";
double test2 = std::stod(test);

std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(7) << test2 << std::endl;
```

PS.  The precision of the number you're trying to convert is too large for a float, you need to use a double or all results from either stof or atof will be wrong.